# Object is not highlighted though it is showing unique in Developer tool for chrome

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automation, salesforce

I am using salesforce application.

we are automating test cases through selenium and writing xpath using Developer tool of chrome.
But for few pages objects are not highlighted when writing xpath and even selenium is unable to perform any action on them.

These pages are loaded through one app and customized.

Comment: Do you have application url? Or could you please add the dom structure here?

Answer (score 0):

check if the objects you what to access are inside a iframe. Is harder to find elements inside a iframe.

You can use the console inside firefox or chrome and in console you can write sentences like :
$x('div')

to be able to find elements with a XPATH sentence. In this example all "div" in a page.

Is much more hard, but with a little practice and thanks the examples here in stackoverflow, you'll be able to find any element.

If you provide an example we can connect we'll try to help!

cheers